# How to calculate probability question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

3 million out of 18 million users could not use their devices as cellphones and that 1 million could not use their devices as a cellphone and for data device.what is the probability that a randomly chosen device could not be used either for data or for voice communication?

My basic approach is by using the below formula $( P(A \cup B) =P(A)+P(B) -P( A \cap B)$
 $P(A \cup B)= P(A) +P(B)- P(A \cap B) = 3/18 + P(B) – 1/18$.

Can someone please guide as above equation has two unknowns. I am confused.

Answer is showing 0.3889

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my perspective, the randomly chosen device that could not be used either for data or for voice communication means that the device cannot be used for data **solely** or cannot be used for voice communication **solely**, but not both at the same time.

To start with, the given probability of not using for data = $\frac {3}{18}$.
However, this event may include an event that the device is not used for both data and voice communication at the same time. 
$$P(not\ for\ data)=P(not\ for\ data\ solely) + P(not\ for\ data \cap not\ for\ voice\ communication)$$
$$P(not\ for\ data\ solely)=P(not\ for\ data)-P(not\ for\ data \cap not\ for\ voice\ communication)$$
$$P(not\ for\ data\ solely)=\frac {3}{18} - \frac{1}{18} = \frac{2}{18}$$

On the other hand, assuming the events that a device is not used for voice communication and data are independent, 
$$P(not\ for\ data \cap not\ for\ voice\ communication)=P(not\ for\ data) \times P(not\ for\ voice\ communication)$$
$$P(not\ for\ voice\ communication)=\frac {1}{18} ÷ \frac {3}{18} = \frac {1}{3}$$

Likewise, this event may include an event that the device is not used for both data and voice communication at the same time. Hence,
$$P(not\ for\ voice\ communication)=P(not\ for\ voice\ communication\ solely) + P(not\ for\ data \cap not\ for\ voice\ communication)$$
$$P(not\ for\ voice\ communication\ solely)=P(not\ for\ voice\ communication)-P(not\ for\ data \cap not\ for\ voice\ communication)$$
$$P(not\ for\ voice\ communication\ solely)=\frac {1}{3} - \frac{1}{18} = \frac{5}{18}$$

Finally, adding up the probability of not using for data **solely** and voice communication **solely** = $\frac {2}{18} + \frac {5}{18} = \frac {7}{18} \approx 0.3889$ (corr. to 4 d.p.)

Comment: Thanks @Diamond Maths for your help.Could you please explain it through venn diagram or the formula i used earlier. I got lost in your second part explanation.

Comment: Thanks very much @Diamond Maths, you really made quite an effort to explain it in detail. Really appreciate your efforts.